# Post routes error in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm facing a problem every time I try to create a post route in Express.

I get a Not found error.

Everything was working well before and I don't know what is really happening

This is my code:

### app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

And this is the users route:

### users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Any help ?

Comment: Can you post the error stack please.

Comment: Are you sure that the HTTP request you send is actually a POST request and not a GET one? (wether it's from a form with `method='post'` or an XHR call?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Try to:

1. **restart the app** and make the post one again, check the logs. You may find an answer in the app logs . If still not working.
2. Verify the **index** path **./routes/index**
3. If you still get not results . **Reinstall** the app again. Looks you are just starting so.

Comment: I tried each step and when I create a new app or get it from wxpress generator the same is happening

Comment: This was posted long before but still helped me. The same error happened and when I restarted, it worked fine.  Thanks for the tip sebastian-salamanca. And how you solved the issue nick-el-mir? Curious to know.